# What does a single quote do in a VBA Where Like

Tags: vba, ms-access, concatenation, wildcard

The following code works to populate the autofill for an Access 2016 combo box, but I don't understand what the single quote is for in the first strRowSource concatenation and also the *' in the third instance, can anyone enlighten me please?

```
Private Sub Supplier_Change()
Dim strRowSource As String
strRowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Purchase ledger].Supplier FROM [Purchase ledger]"
If Len(Me!Supplier.Text) > 2 Then 'when more than 2 characters are entered the following code      will run
 DoCmd.Beep 'Just to confirm subroutine started
 strRowSource = strRowSource & " WHERE Supplier Like '"
 strRowSource = strRowSource & Me!Supplier.Text
 strRowSource = strRowSource & "*'"
 Me!Supplier.RowSource = strRowSource
 Me!Supplier.Dropdown
 End If
 End Sub
```

I'm just looking for an explanation as this code works but I don't understand how.

Comment: Doesn't hearing that Beep with every character typed get annoying?

Comment: Strings in SQL use single quotes. So, your code writes a SQL query with a string in it `LIKE 'xyz*'`

Comment: The beep is just while I'm developing the code so I know that it has been triggered to run, once the code is finalised I will of course remove it.

Comment: You wrote this code and don't understand what it does?

Comment: I adapted it from an example I found on this site, which did not work, so I added a line at a time and when I got an error message I found a fix until the whole thing eventually worked, but as a total beginner I don't understand some of the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are unclear about. The concept applied is "concatenation". The full SQL statement is built incrementally.  Variable strRowSource holds modified value expanded by concatenation to itself on each line (except first line to start the build). You could `Debug.Print strRowSource` after each line in order to view the growing statement in the VBA editor immediate window. Or set a breakpoint and step through code and view the progressive build by examining content of strRowSource after each line.

Code builds an SQL statement that is used as combobox RowSource and filters list as you type. The SQL does pattern matching with asterisk wildcard in WHERE clause to filter combobox list.

Apostrophe (aka single quote) is text delimiter in SQL statement - it or a quote mark (aka double quote) serves same purpose in query object. Delimiters must be in pairs, hence you see concatenation of one before and one after the variable parameter.

More info on wildcards from MS documentation [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-wildcards-in-queries-and-parameters-in-access-ec057a45-78b1-4d16-8c20-242cde582e0b#:~:text=%20Use%20wildcards%20in%20queries%20and%20parameters%20in,view.%20In...%204%20See%20also.%20%20See%20More](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-wildcards-in-queries-and-parameters-in-access-ec057a45-78b1-4d16-8c20-242cde582e0b#:%7E:text=%20Use%20wildcards%20in%20queries%20and%20parameters%20in,view.%20In...%204%20See%20also.%20%20See%20More)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but sorry I don't think I asked my question clearly.  What I would like to know is what changes are made to the string strRowSource after each of the following lines of code; not literally but conceptually:                                        
 strRowSource = strRowSource & " WHERE Supplier Like '"
 strRowSource = strRowSource & Me!Supplier.Text
 strRowSource = strRowSource & "*'"

Comment: I wasn't aware of Debug. Print but that was a very helpful suggestion as I can now see the  SQL statement being constructed i.e.                                                                                                          
                                             
WHERE Supplier Like '
WHERE Supplier Like 'ama
WHERE Supplier Like 'ama*'

WHERE Supplier Like '
WHERE Supplier Like 'amazon
WHERE Supplier Like 'amazon*'

WHERE Supplier Like '
WHERE Supplier Like 'Amazon
WHERE Supplier Like 'Amazon*'

Comment: Basic debugging technique. If an answer resolves question, please mark accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Lets do it one by one
strRowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Purchase ledger].Supplier FROM [Purchase ledger]"
is the start of a query string without a where clause.
Now the following code will add the where clause:
strRowSource = strRowSource & " WHERE Supplier Like '"
strRowSource

is now :

"SELECT DISTINCT [Purchase ledger].Supplier FROM [Purchase ledger]  WHERE Supplier Like '
But it is missing the supplier and the end of the where clause as the field Supplier is a text and not a number. And text fields need to be surrounded by '

Now

strRowSource = strRowSource & Me!Supplier.Text
Here it seems to be that an textbox or similar is used to get the Supplier start we look for. Let's say in this textbox there is: "Foo"

Now we have

"SELECT DISTINCT [Purchase ledger].Supplier FROM [Purchase ledger]  WHERE Supplier Like 'Foo

But the query would fail, cause it has not a closing ' so
strRowSource = strRowSource & "*'"

The query is now:
"SELECT DISTINCT [Purchase ledger].Supplier FROM [Purchase ledger]  WHERE Supplier Like 'Foo*'

The asterisk is telling sql it should not look only for foo but for all Suppliers starting with foo.
And the ' closes the string.

In the end you query all suppliers starting with foo or what is in the respective box.

Have a lot of fun with sql - now you started!

Comment: Thank you that's very helpful, I now see that the first single quote and the later one are connected as a pair (I think?).  I knew that quotes of any kind tend to come in pairs but didn't realise that the pairing could extend over multiple lines.